# R adding dynamic reference line to ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, geom-vline

I tried to use the solution mentioned in this [Add vline to existing plot and have it appear in ggplot2 legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545322/add-vline-to-existing-plot-and-have-it-appear-in-ggplot2-legend#comment107852628_12546102)

However, part of the code doesn't work for my case especially the vline part didn't work. I'm wondering if there are others trick? 
 I have two data set first one is the main dataset:

```
str(sf)
$ date               : chr  "2020-02-02" "2020-02-03" "2020-02-04" "2020-02-05" ...
$ School_Closure_Date: chr  "2020-03-16" "2020-03-16" "2020-03-16" "2020-03-16" ...
$ variable           : Factor w/ 5 levels "cases","deaths",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ value              : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ mindate            : Date, format: "2020-01-24" "2020-01-24" …
$ maxdate            : Date, format: "2020-03-30" "2020-03-30" ...
$ closure            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE …
```

```
 str(sfs)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ fips: int 6075
 $ City: chr "San_Francisco"
 $ date: chr "2020-03-16"
 $ type: chr "school closure"
```

My pupose is to put a vline to the ggplot. However, I got error messeges:

```
        y <- ggplot(sf,aes(date,value)) +            geom_line(aes(group=variable,color=variable))
        x <- geom_vline(data=sfs,xintercept=date,show.legend=TRUE)
        y+x

        Error in UseMethod("rescale") : 
        no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of      class "factor"
        In addition: Warning message:
        Removed 33 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

The y part works but after adding part x, the figure disappeared. Any thought? Thanks for your help!